# delete files of a specific extension if the name meets a condition

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm not sure if this is simple or not, but I have a folder with a lot of csv and txt files. I need to delete all the CSV files that don't have a 0 at the end of their name. I there an easy way to do this?

Just in case the folder is the same folder where my script is so that it is not necessary to enter a file path. I'm running python 3.3.3. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see a problem. There is `os` module for listing files and deleting them. What is your problem?

Comment: Platform? Unix? Windows?

Comment: Ok you are right, not clear enough. I know about the os module, what I don't know is how to go through all the file names to see which ones have the extension I'm looking for and how to apply the condition with the file names. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

In the same vein as Padraic's excellent response:

```
import os, glob
files = [file for file in glob.glob("path/to/files/*.csv") if not file.endswith("0.csv")]
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

I think it looks a little cleaner to build the list first and iterate through to remove. YMMV. I like to do this because then I can go through and write something like:

```
with open("path/to/files/file_removal.log","w") as f:
    for file in files:
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except Exception as e:
            f.write("! The file {} could not be removed:\n".format(file)+
                    "-->{}\n".format(e))
        else:
            f.write("The file {} was removed successfully\n".format(file))
```

Comment: Same here, should be `... if not file.endswith("0.csv")]`. Also `file` is a builtin type and should be avoided as a variable name.

Comment: @remram is that true? Certainly not in py3 but I don't have much experience in py2

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob
import os
for f in glob.glob("*.csv"): # find all csv files
    if not f.endswith("0.csv"):
        os.remove(f)  # if file name ends in 0.csv, delete it
```

Comment: Looks to me like the condition should be `if not f.endswith("0.csv")` to answer OP's question